# toggleClass not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I have an accordion(a kind of). Everything is working, except...

Main rule: clicking on square, showing text, and changing background from gray to red (working),
clicking different, showing text, and changing background to red on clicked square(working)
Clicking the same square, collapse text and changing background color from red to gray (not working). What is wrong with the code?

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/monk7/fcodgwbf/2/)

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.v3').each(function (i) {

    $(this).attr('data-menu', 'nr' + i);
});

$('.describe .describeModule').each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'nr' + i);
});


$('.v3').click(function () {

                $('.v3').removeClass('activeModule');
                $(this).toggleClass( 'activeModule' );

                menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));

                $(".describeModule").not(menu).slideUp("slow");
                menu.slideToggle("slow");
            });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="v3"></div>
<div class="v3"></div>
<div class="v3"></div>
</div>

  <div class="describe">
    <div class="describeModule">one</div>
    <div class="describeModule">two</div>
    <div class="describeModule">three</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the clicked element when you remove the `activeModule` class, this is why in the next line when you call `.toggleClass()`, it adds `activeModule` class to it.

```
$('.v3').not(this).removeClass('activeModule');
```

**Script**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.v3').each(function (i) {

        $(this).attr('data-menu', 'nr' + i);
    });

    $('.describe .describeModule').each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'nr' + i);
    });


    $('.v3').click(function () {

                    $('.v3').not(this).removeClass('activeModule');   //change here skip the clicked element 
                    $(this).toggleClass( 'activeModule' ); 

                    menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));

                    $(".describeModule").not(menu).slideUp("slow");
                    menu.slideToggle("slow");
                });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fcodgwbf/3/)

Comment: Wow! It was fast! Thank you! On jsFiddle working as a charm. Any idea, why wordpress ignore it?

Comment: @Tomu No.. I don't have any idea about wordpress .. sorry!!

Comment: Well, thank you so much for checking and correct me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your remove class call before `toggleClass`. It removes the `activeModule` from the current element also so the `toggleClass` does not know whether the `this` element had the class when the click happened so it will always add the class.

So the solution is to remove the `activeModule` from all elements except from the current element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.v3').each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('data-menu', 'nr' + i);
    });

    $('.describe .describeModule').each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'nr' + i);
    });

    $('.v3').click(function () {
        $('.v3').not(this).removeClass('activeModule');
        $(this).toggleClass('activeModule');

        var menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));

        $(".describeModule").not(menu).slideUp("slow");
        menu.slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c5qcuwyy/)